# Ansible 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013'

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, centos, ansible

I am trying to run my playbook with some vars:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -–extra-vars "env=dev  app=appname 
instance_type=t2.micro  keypair=pem.pem  security_group=sg-XXXX domain=domain  type=microservice"
```

For some reason, it throws the following error:

```
ERROR! Unexpected Exception, this is probably a bug: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 17: ordinal not in range(128)
Traceback (most recent call last):File "/usr/bin/ansible-playbook", 
line 105, in <module>cli.parse() File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/ansible/cli/playbook.py", line 72, in parse super(PlaybookCLI, 
self).parse()File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/cli/__init__.py", line 567, in parse
self.options, self.args = self.parser.parse_args(self.args[1:])File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/optparse.py", 
line 1401, in parse_args
self.error(str(err))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in 
position 17: ordinal not in range(128)`
```

I run the same command without passing the playbook, but still gives the same error.

Is this the right way to use `-–extra-vars`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stop copying commands or playbooks from web browser and type them yourself.

You have a Unicode dash (`u'\u2013'`) somewhere.